# In TYPO3 6.2, remove /fileadmin/ from FAL path (and similar)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, fal

This more of a comprehension question about FAL in TYPO3 6.x.

I understand I can create new storage locations, and that I am not forced to use /fileadmin/ anymore.
As FAL links aren't stored directly in tt_content, I suppose it should be possible to define rewriting rules for FAL links.

E.g. "replace /fileadmin/ by /storage/". Or "for all pages in this branch, remove /fileadmin/ and prepend http://static.domain.com".  Etc.

But - on an integrator level that doesn't involve heavy coding (like in https://github.com/beechit/fal_securedownload) - that's not how it works, or is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the fileadminDir in the install tool, see

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['fileadminDir']
```

FAL Securedownload is only needed if you don't want to reveal the actual location of the file or implement Frontend User based access control for files.